# Read out RTE variable every time I need it or store it in global variable?

Tags: c, rte, autosar

I have a software component with a lot of parameters that I read out of the RTE. Right now I read them from the RTE every time I need them, but I was wondering if it would be better to read them once and store in a global variable. As this is embedded software, space for code and variables is limited. Also execution time is important.
I am not really deep in this topic, so any explanation is welcome :)

Comment: Rich text editor tag - embedded? Do you mean runtime environment?

Comment: Have you looked at the disassembled code to see if the compiler has not already made this operation efficient?

Comment: You want to create a global variable in your SWC and copy the data of an already available "global variable" (RTE), because you are to lazy to use the proper RTE Interfaces? You must have a lot of memory to waste.